# How could I align the "state" and dropdown box with the rest of the inputs and labels

Tags: css

here is the form: http://imgur.com/aB5hTvI

this is the html for the drop down box:

```
<div id = "myForm">
        <form>
            <p> <label for="state">State: </label>
                <select id="state" name="state">
                    <option value="ACT">ACT</option>
                    <option value="NSW">NSW</option>
                    <option value="NT">NT</option>
                    <option value="QLD">QLD</option>
                    <option value="SA">SA</option>
                    <option value="TAS">TAS</option>
                    <option value="VIC">VIC</option>
                    <option value="WA">WA</option>
                </select>
            </p>
       </form>
```

this is my CSS:

```
#myForm {
    margin: auto;
    width: 600px;
}
#myForm form {
    background-color: #E0E0E0;
    text-align: center;
}
#myForm label {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: left;
    width: 150px;
}
#myForm input {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}
#myForm select {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

how could I align the label and dropdown box with the other labels and textboxes. Ive tried "text-align: left" on #myForm select with no noticeable change in the form.

Comment: Added in a fiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/9eyLg73u/2/) but showing the rest of the form and CSS would be nice. From just looking at the code, you can apply a width to the select to match the inputs (150px, 50%, something like that).

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `text-align:left` on the `<p>` tag that contains your *state* select , i.e :

HTML :

```
 <div id = "myForm">
    <form>
        <p id="whatever"> <label for="state">State: </label>
            <select id="state" name="state">
                <option value="ACT">ACT</option>
                <option value="NSW">NSW</option>
                <option value="NT">NT</option>
                <option value="QLD">QLD</option>
                <option value="SA">SA</option>
                <option value="TAS">TAS</option>
                <option value="VIC">VIC</option>
                <option value="WA">WA</option>
            </select>
        </p>
   </form>
 </div>
```

CSS :

Your original css +

```
#whatever {
   text-align:left;
}
```

[See it here](http://jsbin.com/negixubuce/edit?html,css,output)